# Array, change the values of objects that have equal properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, reduce

I have an array, this array contains objects that have properties, for example:
{Name, lat, lng}.

I have to do that if two objects have the same value both of lat and of lng, then I have to modify both the values of lat and lng only in the second object, in a few words I have to add a very small numerical value so that they are different.

Example of an array:

```
var array = [
  {
   "id": "269849444",
   "name": "Ziano Piacentino",
   "lat": 45,
   "lng": 9.4,
  },
  {
   "id": "649296407",
   "name": "Monte Bondone",
   "lat": 46.0315,
   "lng": 11.05685,
  },
  {
   "id": "300151628",
   "name": "Cima Calisio",
   "lat": 46.0977158258,
   "lng": 11.1443512052,
  },
  {
   "id": "266239592",
   "name": "Trient, Trentino-Alto Adige, Italy",
   "lat": 46.0667,
   "lng": 11.1333,
  },
  {
   "id": "130313194355778",
   "name": "Monte Celva",
   "lat": 46.0695882,
   "lng": 11.1783065,
  },
  {
   "id": "217942785",
   "name": "Trento, Italy",
   "lat": 46.0667,
   "lng": 11.1333,
  },
  {
   "id": "478657266",
   "name": "Mercatino di Natale a Levico Terme città da amare",
   "lat": 46.0099217576,
   "lng": 11.3052625593,
  },
  {
   "id": "288554028181059",
   "name": "Fontana Del Nettuno, Trento",
   "lat": 46.0675553413,
   "lng": 11.1213752236,
  },
  {
   "id": "252747884",
   "name": "Duomo di Milano - Milan Cathedral",
   "lat": 45.4646680426,
   "lng": 9.1904055604,
  },
  {
   "id": "213183830",
   "name": "Piacenza",
   "lat": 45.0167,
   "lng": 9.66667,
  },
    {
   "id": "213183830",
   "name": "Home",
   "lat": 45.0167,
   "lng": 9.66667,
  }
 ];
```

Any suggestions?
Even if only solution I think is to use a double for.

Comment: Try to put some work into this, write your own code and show it. You can for example start with a loop over a 2nd loop to compare lat and lng.

Comment: Floats are often not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var array = [...];

array.forEach(function(obj1, key1){
  var increment = 0.000001;
  array.forEach(function(obj2, key2){
    if (key1 != key2){
      if(obj1.lat == obj2.lat && obj1.lng == obj2.lng){
        array[key2].lat += increment;
        array[key2].lng += increment;
        increment += 0.000001;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, why did you change the solution?
a.forEach((o,k) => { a.forEach ((u,q) => { if (k!=q) { if (o.lat == u.lat && o.lng == u.lng) { a[q].lat + = 0.000001; a[q].lng + = 0.000001; return false; } }});});

Comment: This change was to increase every time you are repeating a die. The first solution was only for 2 repeated values, but the current solution is available for 2,3,4,5,... repeats of values.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to solving a problem with code are:

- Understand the problem
- Understand what you need to to do to solve it
- Plan it out in pseudocode
- Code

Congratulations, the first two steps are completed. I can help out with the third and you'll be ready for the fourth!

---

The most basic approach would be to have two loops, where you search each item in the array until you find one that matches the criteria and carry out what you need to do.

**The following is not actual code syntax, it's pseudocode. A way for you to understand more in depth what road to take in order to solve your problem.**

```
var array = {...}    
for elementA in array {
   for elementB in array{
       //First you have to make sure you are not comparing the same value in the array with itself
       if elementA.index is different from elementB.index then {
            if elementA equals elementB {
                change elementB
             }
       }
   }
}
```

So what you do in this pseudocode is take an element from your array, and match it against all the other items in the same array. You have to be careful not to try and match against itself, one way to avoid this is by comparing the item's index position, if they are different, you can be pretty sure that it's not same item. Once you passed that hurdle, all you have to do then is ask if they are the same (in your case that would specifically be if they have the same values for `lat` and `lng`). If they are, then all you have to do is change `elementB`, which is the second element compared.

That's it!

Hope that helps set you on the right path. You can get more out of StackOverflow if you offer a bit of how you've approached the problem, instead of asking for a raw answer.

Comment: In reality I just wanted an opinion, but it seems that that part of the message was canceled and I did not understand why.
I thank you for your message, I think the only solution is with double for. ;)

Comment: It would have been better then to word your question differently. Along the lines of "Is there another way to do this aside from two loops?" and offer your first approach. Maybe next time :)